# Python 3.8.3 Installations Error: python.exe - System Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently attempted to install Python 3.8.3, and trying to launch the IDLE(shell) ,I am getting following error:

[image: python.exe installation error]

> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

Comment: You probably had a version of python already installed. Uninstall all versions of python, launchers and idle editor. Then reinstall cleanly. That will fix it. This seems to be happening when installing 3.8 on top of existing installations.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for your version of Windows (x64)

For Windows x64: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

For Windows x86: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe

Answer (score 0):

This link provides you with multiple solutions. (May not be related to python)

https://medium.com/@zaynwilder55/how-to-fix-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-5928d447b40d

This problem occurs due to Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio . Updating or repairing it might fix the issue.